Overlap issues with a transparent table

As shown above, when I scroll down the body of the table is visible under the header due to the transparent background. Ideally, I would like to keep this transparency, how could I hide the section of the table body underneath the header?
The background is going to animated in some way with the table having a backdrop-filter to create a frosted glass effect.
I have tried using the clip-path property in CSS with no success there, as well as putting the table body in a div but that messes up the fixed spacing of the tables columns.


const data = [
  { name: "Player 1", playFabPlayerID: "12345" },
  { name: "Player 2", playFabPlayerID: "67890" },
  { name: "Player 3", playFabPlayerID: "54321" },
  { name: "Player 4", playFabPlayerID: "09876" },
  { name: "Player 5", playFabPlayerID: "11223" },
  { name: "Player 6", playFabPlayerID: "44556" },
];

const tb = document.getElementById("pt-body");

data.map((item, index) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.key = index;
  tr.innerHTML = `
    <td class="pt-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td class="playfab">${item.playFabPlayerID}</td>
    <td class="actions">
      <button type="button">B</button>
      <button type="button">K</button>
    </td>
  `;

  tb.appendChild(tr);
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #121212;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pseudo-table-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.pseudo-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table thead {
  background-color: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.pseudo-table th,
.pseudo-table td {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.pseudo-table th {
  font-weight: 450;
}

.pseudo-table td {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions-header {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#header-search {
  width: 128px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}

.pt-checkbox {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.pt-checkbox input {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: #4a72ff 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pt-checkbox input:checked {
  background-color: #4a72ff;
}
<div class="pseudo-table-container">
  <table class="pseudo-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="pt-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <th>
          Name
          <input id="header-search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </th>
        <th>PlayFabPlayerID</th>
        <th class="actions-header">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pt-body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>




If this is the real color of your body, thead > tr { background-color: #121212 } will do the job for you. I know it's not transparent but it's acting like. this could work for any color unless you have a gradient color or an image as background for your body.

I've added some more clarification to the post, thank you for the answer and edit.

You can achieve this relatively easily by playing with z-index and pseudo-elements... You create layers with a fully transparent header, and set what would be the quasi-background of the header.

You can use position: sticky for the table header,
change the background-color of the header with the z-index the header will be above the table.


const data = [
  { name: "Player 1", playFabPlayerID: "12345" },
  { name: "Player 2", playFabPlayerID: "67890" },
  { name: "Player 3", playFabPlayerID: "54321" },
  { name: "Player 4", playFabPlayerID: "09876" },
  { name: "Player 5", playFabPlayerID: "11223" },
  { name: "Player 6", playFabPlayerID: "44556" },
];

const tb = document.getElementById("pt-body");

data.map((item, index) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.key = index;
  tr.innerHTML = `
    <td class="pt-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td class="playfab">${item.playFabPlayerID}</td>
    <td class="actions">
      <button type="button">B</button>
      <button type="button">K</button>
    </td>
  `;

  tb.appendChild(tr);
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #121212;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pseudo-table-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: relative;
}

.pseudo-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table thead {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); 
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; 
}

.pseudo-table th,
.pseudo-table td {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.pseudo-table th {
  font-weight: 450;
}

.pseudo-table td {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions-header {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#header-search {
  width: 128px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}

.pt-checkbox {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.pt-checkbox input {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: #4a72ff 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pt-checkbox input:checked {
  background-color: #4a72ff;
}
<div class="pseudo-table-container">
  <table class="pseudo-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="pt-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <th>
          Name
          <input id="header-search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </th>
        <th>PlayFabPlayerID</th>
        <th class="actions-header">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pt-body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>




OP already uses position: sticky and z-index has no effect here. you just changed the background-color of the table header.

I don't quite understand what you want. But you can use text-shadow:


const data = [
  { name: "Player 1", playFabPlayerID: "12345" },
  { name: "Player 2", playFabPlayerID: "67890" },
  { name: "Player 3", playFabPlayerID: "54321" },
  { name: "Player 4", playFabPlayerID: "09876" },
  { name: "Player 5", playFabPlayerID: "11223" },
  { name: "Player 6", playFabPlayerID: "44556" },
];

const tb = document.getElementById("pt-body");

data.map((item, index) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.key = index;
  tr.innerHTML = `
    <td class="pt-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td class="playfab">${item.playFabPlayerID}</td>
    <td class="actions">
      <button type="button">B</button>
      <button type="button">K</button>
    </td>
  `;

  tb.appendChild(tr);
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #121212;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pseudo-table-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.pseudo-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table thead {
  background-color: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.pseudo-table th,
.pseudo-table td {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.pseudo-table th {
  font-weight: 450;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 20px #000, 1px 1px 20px #000, 0 -1px 20px #000, -1px -1px 20px #000, 0 1px 20px #000, 1px 1px 20px #000, 0 -1px 20px #000, -1px -1px 20px #000;
}

.pseudo-table td {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions-header {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions {
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.pseudo-table .actions button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#header-search {
  width: 128px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}

.pt-checkbox {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.pt-checkbox input {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: #4a72ff 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

th.pt-checkbox input{
  background-color: #121212;
}

.pt-checkbox input:checked {
  background-color: #4a72ff;
}
<div class="pseudo-table-container">
  <table class="pseudo-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="pt-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <th>
          Name
          <input id="header-search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </th>
        <th>PlayFabPlayerID</th>
        <th class="actions-header">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pt-body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>



